# Using Processing 2.0 in Netbeans throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, class, netbeans, nullpointerexception, processing

So I'm using Processing 2.0 in Netbeans 7.4, and have managed to get it successfully working in the main class. However, when I try and extend another class from PApplet I get a NPE error when trying to use a simple rect() function through an object in the main class.

The main class is called ProcessingApp and contains the main function, while the class I'm trying to get to work with processing functions is called processing (sorry if the similar names get confusing)

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.rect(PApplet.java:11934)
    at processing.processing.thing(processing.java:16)
    at processing.ProcessingApp.draw(ProcessingApp.java:16)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2306)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Main class:

```
package processing;
import processing.core.*;



public class ProcessingApp  extends PApplet{
    processing p = new processing();
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      PApplet.main(new String[]{"processing.ProcessingApp"});
   }
   public void setup(){
       size(1000,800);
   }
   public void draw(){
       p.thing();
   }
}
```

And the class I'm trying to get processing functions to work in:

```
package processing;
import processing.core.*;

public class processing extends PApplet {

    public void thing(){
        rect(0,0,50,100);
    }
}
```

These are all test classes for a larger project but the fact is that they both throw the same errors whenever I try and incur the rect() function, or really any processing function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, && thank you for taking the time to read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to have two Processing windows displayed (or more accurately, two canvasses), only one of your classes should extend `PApplet`, and your other class should use the `PApplet` from the first class to draw.  Otherwise, your second `PApplet` is trying to draw to a `null` canvas, since you never called `setup()` on it.

One possible solution is as follows:

```
public class Processing { // Note that class names should be capitalized by convention

    public void thing(PApplet pApplet){
        pApplet.rect(0,0,50,100);
    }
}
```

Which would turn your draw method into:

```
public void draw() {
    p.thing(this);
}
```

Comment: OH MY SWEET JESUS YOU ARE AMAZING I LOVE YOU THANK YOU OH GOD-- sorry this is just really helpful and you probably saved my comp sci course mark, thank you

Comment: I'll hit accept it but unfortunately I can't upvote just yet :)